# How to replace old item with new item in a list inside while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to append current price from a web socket to a list so I can format it and use it for some calculations. However it keeps appending items and expanding list. I want to keep only one instance and keep replacing it with new one.

Example:

```
res_array = []
bm = None

while True:

    def process_message(msg):
        global count, res_array, bm
        res_array.append(msg['c'])
        return res_array

    def initiate():
        global bm
        client = Client(api_key="11111111",
                        api_secret="22222222")
        bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
        conn_key = bm.start_symbol_ticker_socket('BNBBTC', process_message)
        bm.start()

    initiate()
    print(res_array)
```

Comment: But you are explicitly using **res_array.append(msg['c'])**, it does append.

Comment: I don't understand. If you only want to keep one instance, why are you using a list? You only need a list if you want to store _multiple_ values.

Comment: @Aran-Fey For some reason I didn't manage to do it with variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep only a single value at a time, you can do

```
res_array.clear()
res_array.append(msg['c'])
```

Comment: Why are you getting `res_array` explicitly from the `globals` table instead of just using it "normally"? `res_array.clear()` and `res_array.append(msg['c'])` will both work perfectly fine even if `res_array` isn't local

Comment: I haven’t seen that the user has already used global keyword with res_array , yea it will also work without gloabls()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely replace the contents of a list, you can do that with

```
some_list[:] = new_contents
```

Answer (score 0):

In your process_message function, you can simply create a copy of the old list, append the item to the copied list, then replace the old list with the copied list.

```
def process_message(msg):
    global count,res_array,bm
    new_res_array = list(res_array) #creates copy of res_array
    new_res_array.append(msg['c'])
    res_array = new_res_array
    return res_array
```

Not sure why you would want to do something like that though.